# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, error-handling, model

please help me to fix this problem

```
X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
X_test = np.asarray(X_test)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                epochs=75, 
                batch_size=batch_size, 
                verbose=2, 
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
                callbacks= [lrate])
```

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'
even I converted into numpy array, but getting error. please help. thank you.

Comment: What did you convert into a numpy array? Which array is sparse, and where's the supposed conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be easier if we had a more precise idea of what is stored in X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test before you do the asarray. You might try using the (copy=True) version of array conversion : numpy.array(X_train)

Comment: version of array conversion?